# Taking difference between column containing dates and today (using vetorization)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, vectorization

I am trying to avoid loops as this is just a subset of the bigger dataframe I have which has over 30k rows. All I want to do is create a new column with difference between the date in that row and today's date.

What's the best way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07','2014-04-08', '2014-04-09'],

})
```

Comment: `df['diff'] = datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: you can use `pd.Timestamp('now')` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['diff'] = (datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).dt.days
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_date_time(df['Date'])
df['num_days_diff'] = (np.datetime64('today', 'D') - df['Date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```